# Upgrade ubuntu from 20.04.1 to 20.04.2

Tags: 20.04

Why is my ubuntu 20.04.1 not upgrading 20.04.2. Ubuntu 20.04.2 is released begin february.....

> Linux redman-desktop 5.8.0-44-generic #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Can somebody help me

Comment: Have you `sudo apt update` to update your software lists, and then assuming no errors `sudo apt full-upgrade` to install all upgraded packages?  What errors did you get?  Does `lsb_release -a` show 20.04.2?  (or what are you looking at that tells you 20.04.1, some results show your installation media so will remain 20.04.1 or 20.04)

Comment: I probably made the mistake that 'uname -a' should show the upgraded version...
'lsb_release -a' shows ubuntu 20.04.2.....

Comment: `uname` provides kernel details; which frequently can't even tell you what release you're using  (eg. a 20.04 LTS system using the GA kernel will use 5.4, as will a 18.04 LTS system using the HWE kernel; 5.4 as its intentionally the same kernel).

Comment: Thanks for the information..... @guiverc